# How to use Auto Layout to stack views vertically in portrait mode and horizontally in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I've got two views 'View A' and 'View B'. I'd like to display them side by side in landscape mode but one over the other in portrait mode. How can I achieve this using Auto Layout?[image: Views stacked side by side in Landscape]

[image: Views stacked top to bottom in Portrait]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written in a UIViewController's -viewDidLoad method:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

// Assuming viewA and viewB have already been setup and have their 
// translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property set to NO

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewA,viewB);

NSArray *a1, *a2, *a3, *a4, *a5, *a6, *a7, *a8;

// Construct all of the constraints
a1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[viewA]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
a2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[viewB]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
a3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[viewA][viewB]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
a4 = @[[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewB attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:viewA attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
self.portraitConstraints = @[a1,a2,a3,a4];

a5 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[viewA][viewB]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
a6 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[viewA]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
a7 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[viewB]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
a8 = @[[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewB attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:viewA attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

self.landscapeConstraints = @[a5,a6,a7,a8];

// Add all of the constraints
for (NSArray *constraints in self.portraitConstraints) {
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}
for (NSArray *constraints in self.landscapeConstraints) {
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}

// Activate the constraints based on the orientation
void(^constraintBlock)() = ^{
    // I'm using 'active' property instead of adding and removing constraints.  I haven't 
    // checked to see which way is "better" but it works well so I won't bother!
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation])) {
        for (NSArray *constraints in self.landscapeConstraints) {
            for (NSLayoutConstraint *c in constraints) {
                c.active = NO;
            }
        }
        for (NSArray *constraints in self.portraitConstraints) {
            for (NSLayoutConstraint *c in constraints) {
                c.active = YES;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (NSArray *constraints in self.portraitConstraints) {
            for (NSLayoutConstraint *c in constraints) {
                c.active = NO;
            }
        }
        for (NSArray *constraints in self.landscapeConstraints) {
            for (NSLayoutConstraint *c in constraints) {
                c.active = YES;
            }
        }

    }
};

// Call the block immediately to setup the constraints
constraintBlock();

// self.observer is a property I would then use in the viewController's -dealloc 
// method to remove it as an observer of the default NSNotificationCenter
self.observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    // Update the constraints whenever the status bar orientation changes
    constraintBlock();
}];
```

There are many other ways you could do this as well!

Comment: I wish I could do this in IB using size classes. But this works nevertheless. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With the new `UIStackView` *(introduced in iOS 9.0)* it is now easily possible. Just add a UIStackView in the storyboard with your two views and define the desired proportion.

Then in the ViewController you can adapt the alignment of the axis directly on orientation change:

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation {
    case .Portrait:
        self.stackview.axis = .Vertical
    case .PortraitUpsideDown:
        self.stackview.axis = .Vertical
    case .LandscapeLeft:
        self.stackview.axis = .Horizontal
    case .LandscapeRight:
        self.stackview.axis = .Horizontal
    default:
        self.stackview.axis = .Vertical
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting iOS 8, you can take advantage the new [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html). While this won't help with previous versions of the OS, it certainly will be an asset for iOS 8+.

You can do this in Interface Builder by selecting a view controller and enabling size classes:

[image]

Then, when building your view, set the size class you want to create constraints for at the bottom of the Storyboard window:

[image]

You can also add, modify, and delete size class-specific constraints right from a constraint's property inspector view:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way to set up such a layout which automatically follows your requests. In iOS8 with the help of Size Classes (as was already mentioned in a previous answer) you can do that, but only for iPhones, which change classes on orientation change. Since your examples had layouts for iPads there is no such thing, you have to track orientations by yourself and change layout accordingly.

EDIT:
Actually, as long as you do iPad only layout or you do universal layout but iPhone and iPad has the same one and it changes only on orientation changes, there is an hack which will behave as desired:
Present your view controller embedded in a container view controller, and in the container override `-viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` and forcibly change the traits of your controller by calling `-setOverrideTraitCollection:forChildViewController:` with traits relative to the new size of the container (e.g.: size.width > size.height is `UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular` on horizontal and `UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact` on vertical).

The problem with this procedure is that it changes the way this view controller is perceived by all the other classes that use its traits.